# How to find out what type of RAID was used and possibly mounting the drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, samba, raid

I found a hard drive that I used in a file server years ago using Ubuntu with Samba. I would like to see if anything on the drive is recoverable. There were 2 drives and one got wiped. I don't remember what type of RAID was used; Possibly 0. If this was the case, then I know there's nothing I can do:

[image: Screenshot]

I couldn't get any info in Windows, so I booted up Ubuntu on a flash drive and tried to take a look and still don't understand how to tell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Based on the information given in the question I do not think anyone can help you with this. How do you know the drive will even work? You imply it is quite old.

Comment: What does `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb` or `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1` tell you? 

Comment: At least do you know what tool you used to create a RAID array? It could be a hardware raid and on the software side there are also multiple options (mdadm, LVM, ZFS).

Comment: I get "cannot open /dev/sdb1: Permission denied" when I run mdadm.

Comment: I do not remember the tool used to create the array. The only thing I remember it being is software.

Comment: Ok well I guess I figured it out: GParted now says under "Label" that it's "RAID 0" so apparently that answers that.